# window.addEventListener on load activates only one time on Opera browser

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

so I'm having this strange bug. Everything works fine for Google Chrome browser, but on Opera browser something is wrong with this code. The point of this code is to do two things:

1. It gets flatpickr-input class first element and attachs id element on it
2. It gets _dates[] class and attachs ID elements on them

Also it gets hp-form__field--date-range class and places a placeholder on its input field.

This has to be done on each page load, so other function could start working - basically it gets value from selected date and attaches it to _dates[] created IDs, so the search would work for 1 selected date, as it was originally working for two selected dates, for example https://dev11.getspace.us/plan.online/?post_type=hp_listing&_category=&s=&_dates%5B%5D=2022-09-30&_dates%5B%5D=2022-09-30&place=&languages= - search is working from 2022-09-30 until 2022-09-30 (#first_date - #second_date). This script is working fine on Chrome, but on Opera it only works for first time, after reload nothing is working. What could be wrong with this code, so it's not working only on Opera / Safari? Basically i'm trying to attach id elements on page load, so setInterval function could find it and start working.

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        const date = document.getElementsByClassName('flatpickr-input')[0];
date.id = "data_pagrindine";
const first_date = document.getElementsByName('_dates[]')[0];
first_date.id = 'first_date';

const second_date = document.getElementsByName('_dates[]')[1];
second_date.id = 'second_date';
document.getElementsByClassName("hp-form__field--date-range")[0].querySelectorAll('input')[1].placeholder = "Pasirinkite datą";
        });

setInterval(
  function(){ 
const input = document.getElementById('data_pagrindine');
input.addEventListener('change', updateValue); },
  4000
);
function updateValue() {
    var value = document.getElementById('data_pagrindine').value;
    document.getElementById('first_date').value=value;
    document.getElementById('second_date').value=value;
}
```

[Video of bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0s58LUgHkpI)

Comment: window `load` event fires only once in all browsers. Also, do you realise that `input.addEventListener('change', updateValue);` runs every 4 seconds? in other words, you keep adding the same event listener over and over and over

Comment: How can I change window load function, so it would start at each page load? So basically nothing would be gone after page refresh

Comment: `so it would start at each page load` - it does already, once on each page load - perhaps you don't understand what a page load is and that's the issue - just because some content is added to a page, or even sometimes when the page seems to load completely new content, it isn't actually a new page being loaded ... have you heard of the "Single Page Application"

Comment: I haven't heard about single page application, as I'm pretty new with Javascript. But basically as I understand I need to change the whole code, but the biggest problem is to attach id fields so functions could find them..